# Retrieving Keypoints from cv2.cuda_ORB.detectAndComputeAsync

Tags: python, opencv, homography

Good morning,

I'm getting stuck trying to develop homography using the CUDA bindings provided in OpenCV for Python 3.7.7. I am able to successfully get homography to work on the CPU (for image alignment), but the speed is not up to par, so I've been trying to get some of the below operations onto the GPU.

When I run the CPU code, everything works as expected. However, when I try to port everything over to the GPU I get problematic results. As you can see in the images below, the CPU version returns a list of cv2.KeyPoint() keypoints for the "orb.detectAndCompute" functions; however, the GPU version returns a cv2.cuda_GpuMat() for its "orb.detectAndComputeAsync" functions. I can't use that, so I call "download()" on the GPU mat (which is supposed to be the list of keypoints) but am confronted with a numpy array with values I don't recognize and can't use.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with how OpenCV returns the results? I need to get the results from the GPU to match the format returned by the CPU version (a list of cv2.KeyPoint()).

CPU Results (orb.detectAndCompute):
[cpu-results (note: results go to 299 in this picture, I can only show the first 9)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcO7o.png)

GPU Results (before "download()" is called):
[pre-download-results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6BFl.png)

GPU results (after "download()" is called):
[post-download-results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoQhe.png)

CPU code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def align_image(image_gray: np.ndarray, reference_gray: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:

    # Detect ORB features and compute descriptors.
    max_features = 500
    orb = cv2.ORB.create(max_features)
    image_keypoints, image_descriptors = orb.detectAndCompute(image_gray, None)
    reference_keypoints, reference_descriptors = orb.detectAndCompute(reference_gray, None)

    # Match features.
    matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING)
    matches = matcher.match(image_descriptors, reference_descriptors, None)

    # Sort matches by score
    matches.sort(key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)

    # Limit matches (0.21 is the sweet spot)
    good_matches = int(len(matches) * 0.21)
    matches = matches[:good_matches]

    # Extract location of good matches
    image_points = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
    reference_points = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)

    for i, match in enumerate(matches):
        image_points[i, :] = image_keypoints[match.queryIdx].pt
        reference_points[i, :] = reference_keypoints[match.trainIdx].pt

    # Find homography
    M, _ = cv2.findHomography(image_points, reference_points, cv2.RANSAC)

    # Use homography to align the image to the reference
    height, width = reference_gray.shape
    aligned_image = cv2.warpPerspective(image_gray, M, (width, height))

    return aligned_image
```

Below is the start of the GPU code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read the images as normal
npMat1 = cv2.imread("path_to_image_to_be_corrected")
npMat2 = npMat1.copy()#cv2.imread("path_to_reference_image")

# Load the images onto the GPU
cuMat1 = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
cuMat2 = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
cuMat1.upload(npMat1)
cuMat2.upload(npMat2)

# Convert the color on the GPU
cuMat1 = cv2.cuda.cvtColor(cuMat1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cuMat2 = cv2.cuda.cvtColor(cuMat2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Create the CUDA ORB detector and detect keypoints/descriptors
kps1, descs1 = orb.detectAndComputeAsync(cuMat1, None) # Both are returned as GPU Mats
kps2, descs2 = orb.detectAndComputeAsync(cuMat2, None)

# Download the keypoints from the GPU memory
kps1_downloaded = kps1.download()
kps2_downloaded = kps2.download()
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of download() this should work:

```
kps1 = orb.convert(kps1)
kps2 = orb.convert(kps2)
```

OpenCV 4.5.0